# Not all projects under the same solution see the NuGet package

Tags: visual-c++, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have a C++ solution that has two projects under it. One project is generating a `.lib` library and the other project uses it and generate a `.exe` executable on Visual Studio 2019. The first project uses pthread and they both had a path to the pthread library in their properties.

I wanted to move from an "external" pthread library to use the library from NuGet. I downloaded pthread from NuGet and removed the path of the exteranl library from the properties of both project.

As a result, the first project compiles with no problems, but the second project fails due to:

> Error C1083   Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory

Also, when opening the properties for both projects, in the properties of the first project I can see that "Project Master Settings" and "Referenced Packages" categories appeared, but they do not appear in the second project.

How do I make it so that both projects can use the NuGet package?

Comment: Hi, what the project type of your two projects?

Comment: How did you install the nuget package for the two projects? Did you install the nuget package by right-clicking on the Solution or the projects?

Answer (score 0):

> Also, when opening the properties for both projects, in the properties
>   of the first project I can see that "Project Master Settings" and
>   "Referenced Packages" categories appeared, but they do not appear in
>   the second project.
>
> How do I make it so that both projects can use the NuGet package?

**The issue** is that you do not install the nuget package `pthreads` into the second project at the same time. Using Project Reference or any other for C++ will not copy the file `pthread.h` into the second project.

l think you just install the nuget package called [pthreads](https://www.nuget.org/packages/pthreads/) into lib library project and then the `.exe` project references the lib project. In this situation, the `pthread.h` file will not copy from the first project to the second project, which really different from `.Net` projects.

**Actually**, you should install the nuget package in every project which uses it.

**Solution**

So to solve it, you should install the **pthreads** nuget package on the second project at the same time. Right-click on the **project**(which it does not have the menu`Referenced Packages`)-->select `Manage NuGet Packages` and search the nuget **pthreads** to install.

**Besides**, if the whole solution's projects all use this nuget package, you can right-click on the **solution**-->choose `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...`

[image]

**In addition**, when you build the project and face this error **Error C2011 'timespec': 'struct' type redefinition**, you can add this code on the top of the `#include<pthread.h>`:

```
#define HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC
```

[image]

Hope it could help you.

Comment: They both seem to have the same NuGet package manager and it shows that the package is installed for both, I tried to uninstall and install it from the other project, it didn't work. I'm giving up and turning back to the "normal" method of just having the library and pointing to it.

Comment: l wonder what is the type of your c++ projects and please share it with me . You can just follow my steps: create a new c++ static Library project and a c++ console application. Second, right-click on every project in the `solution explorer`,choose `nuget package manager `, input `pthreads` in the search box and you would better choose the latest version 2.9.1.4 to install. After that, click `install`. To check whether the nuget installs in the project, you can right-click on  the project-->Nuget Package Manager-->Installed to check whether `pthreads` exists in it.

Comment: Finally, you can add any project reference for each other. In my side, there is no such error, and when you install the package, please clean the nuget cache first by `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Nuget Package Manager`-->`General`-->`Clean all Nuget Caches`.  And share the project type info with us, we can judge whether it is the issue of specific project types are not supported or any other.